# Calculating the linear function in a Neural Network vs in a neuron

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

When implementing the forward propagation in a 2 NN layer, Andrew NG used

```
Z1 = np.dot(W1,X)+b1
A1 = np.tanh(Z1)
Z2 = np.dot(W2,A1)+b2
A2 = sigmoid(Z2)
```

But when implementing a single neuron, he used

```
A = sigmoid(np.dot(w.T,X)+b)
```

My question is, where/why did the transpose disappear in the 2 NN layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When taking [dot products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product), or [multiplying matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), the adjacent dimmensions need to match:

$$
\overbrace{\mathbf{A}}^{(m \times k)} \overbrace{\mathbf{B}}^{(k \times n)} = \overbrace{\mathbf{C}}^{(m \times n)}
$$

So take another look at the notes, or code, and check what are the dimensions of the objects. If they are vectors, are they column vectors $(n \times 1)$, or row vectors $(1 \times n)$? This should clarify things for you.